# Objective-C: why is this property assignment not working as expected?

Tags: objective-c

I'm still sometimes puzzled when it comes to details of Objective-C.

Having this header file:
.h:

```
   AVCaptureSession *capSession;
   @property(nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureSession *capSession;
```

Why is it correct in ObjC to do this:

.m:

```
// Create instance locally, then assign to property and release local instance.
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
self.capSession = session;
[session release];
```

and why is it incorrect/not working/resulting in incorrect behavior to do that:

.m:

```
// Directly assign to property.
    self.capSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
```

The main problem I see is that I'm missing a "release" in the 2nd version. Would it be okay to use "autorelease" as an alternative:

```
  self.capSession = [[[AVCaptureSession alloc] init] autorelease];
```

René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your `autorelease` alternative is fine.  The `alloc`/`init` way of creating objects gives you a retained object.  Then you use your accessor via `self.capSession = session`, which calls `retain` again, so you need to `release` it.  `autorelease` will end up being the same.

Comment: Thanks. So I'll stick with the auto release version (which version is better coding style?).

Remaining problem is: when I'm done with my "capSession", I call 
[self.capSession stopRunning];
self.capSession = nil;

But as soon as I put the "nil" line in, the app crashes. What's the problem? A new session is created every time (see code above).

Comment: Would it also be correct to:
 self.capSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
 [self.capSession release];

?